# accessibility issue with JAWS reading entire unordered list items

Tags: jquery, accessibility, validation, jaws-screen-reader

I have a form which displays validation errors in ul li format, on submit the focus is forced on the first error message in li list. But jaws is reading the whole list instead of the focused text. Tabindex has been added to each li item, but on tab key press focus is going on li item but jaws not reading but reading sometimes with 'i' keypress.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. A list such as a `ul` is perceived by JAWS as a whole. *I* is the quick navigation key to move to the next list item.
What you can do here is to use the `aria-invalid` attribute and assign the `alert` role to your first `li`, as suggested [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-invalid_attribute).

Comment: "aria-invalid" is used generally in form fields as per my understanding.  Can you please elaborate more on this method of using aria-invalid with role="alert" on li and the jaws behavior with this implementation

Comment: So you don't want to direct the user to the field that is invalid, you just want to show the error message, am I right? If so, you would need only the `alert` role on your first `li`. Some code would be helpful, though :).

Comment: <div data-default-msg="The required fields below in red were not completed." id="err-msg" class="err-msg" tabindex="0">

<ul>

<li>The required fields below in red were not completed.</li>

<li>TThe First Name field was not completed.</li>

<li>The Last Name field was not completed.</li>

</ul>

</div>



On submit the focus is forced on the first li item, which is not read by JAWS but can see the focused li element. 

Note: This list of error messages are populated by jquery validator.

Comment: OK, I'll try to test and improve the answer. But please tag it also as jQuery Validator, because I do know that @JörnZaefferer, its author, considers accessibility as a very important thing.